# Correct way to use Google Cloud Storage SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to list of files in my GCP bucket using Google Cloud Storage SDK using scala.

For example I have a bucket named `bucket-1` and there is a folder inside it `folder-1` and I want to list all the files inside `folder-1`.

I tried using below code but it doesn't return anything inside `folder-1`

```
val files = storage.list("bucket-1",BlobListOption.currentDirectory(), BlobListOption.prefix("folder-1"))
```

The problem is objects/files inside the `folder-1` doesn't have any set prefix due to which I can't add it in `BlobListOption.prefix` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all the files in the directory `folder-1` your prefix should be `folder-1/`and you should specify a delimiter of `/`.

objects will be in the returned `items` array. Directories (which do not exists and are emulated) are returned in the `prefixes` array.

Comment: I tried the prefix as `folder-1/` but can you please help me with how to pass the delimiter option. I don't see any such parameter.

Comment: Here is the link to the Google REST API that shows the various parameters including `delimiter`: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list Then lookup that feature in the library that you are using.

Comment: Hey Thanks. But I'm using SDK and couldn't find any such option there.

Comment: For your code did you change `folder-1` to `folder-1/`? If you look at the `currentDirectory()` API, it looks like this handles the delimiter automatically. https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.BlobListOption.html

Comment: Yes, I tried using `folder-1/ ` but it doesn't return anything inside the folder. It just returns 1 item, which is the `folder-1` itself.

Also I'm using `iterateAll()` method to loop over all the returned files.